# pst-circ: figure and caption overlapping

Tags: floats, pstricks

I'm writing a thesis and need to get this problem solved.
I just started to use `pst-circ` as an alternative to `cirtuitikz` (seemed to me like it has better documentation), however I'm kinda stuck with the caption overlapping partially the circuit.

I don't know if I should use `\vspace{something}`, but I was looking for a cleaner solution (if possible). I'm not really sure I used the correct encapsulation. Maybe I should use a minipage as well.

[image]

I used the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](9,8)
    \Cnode(0,0){P1} \psdot(P1) \nput[labelsep=0.25]{180}{P1}{R}
    \Cnode(9,0){P2} \psdot(P2) \nput[labelsep=0.25]{0}{P2}{S}   
    \pnode(4,0){C}

    \multidipole(P1)(C)
        \coil{$L$}      
        \capacitor{$C$}.

    \multidipole(P2)(C)
        \coil{$L$}      
        \capacitor{$C$}.
\end{pspicture}

    \caption{Filtre LC simple en configuration étoile}
    \label{filtre_lc_etoile_simple}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

(ignore the text inside the caption: it doesn't make any sense at all, since this is just a truncated copy-paste from another part of the document)

I'm not sure this is really a `pst-circ` problem: it may be a regular figure problem (though using external PNG / PDF files as source I never got this behaviour), maybe because dimensions where specified and known.

I encapsulated between a figure because I wanted to add some caption to it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `shift=` option for `pspicture` to change the baseline (default is set at the bottom of the box):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}[shift=0.5](9,8)
    \Cnode(0,0){P1} \psdot(P1) \nput[labelsep=0.25]{180}{P1}{R}
    \Cnode(9,0){P2} \psdot(P2) \nput[labelsep=0.25]{0}{P2}{S}   
    \pnode(4,0){C}

    \multidipole(P1)(C)
        \coil{$L$}      
        \capacitor{$C$}.

    \multidipole(P2)(C)
        \coil{$L$}      
        \capacitor{$C$}.
\end{pspicture}

    \caption{Filtre LC simple en configuration étoile}
    \label{filtre_lc_etoile_simple}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On a side note, I used `\centering` instead of the `center` environment to avoid adding extra undesired vertical spacing.

Comment: Seems a good and easy solution. Sorry for my delayed reply ;)

Answer (score 4):

Gonzalo's answer certainly works, however I would recommend that, in general, you take a different approach.

The general syntax for the `pspicture` environment is

```
\begin{pspicture}(xmin,ymin)(xmax,ymax)
```

but as you've demonstrated, you can leave off `(xmin,ymin)` and it will default to `(0,0)`. This puts a single box of the given size in the document. The drawing itself will be done by postscript.

If you use `\psgrid`

```
\begin{pspicture}(9,8)
\psgrid
...
```

then you get

[image]

which highlights a few things

- `ymin` is clearly not small enough
- `ymax` is far too big

So, one solution is to use

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,1)
\psgrid
```

which gives

[image]

and this seems a bit closer to what you want. Now that you're done constructing, you can remove `\psgrid`

Here's a complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,1)
    \psgrid
    \Cnode(0,0){P1} \psdot(P1) \nput[labelsep=0.25]{180}{P1}{R}
    \Cnode(9,0){P2} \psdot(P2) \nput[labelsep=0.25]{0}{P2}{S}   
    \pnode(4,0){C}

    \multidipole(P1)(C)
        \coil{$L$}      
        \capacitor{$C$}.

    \multidipole(P2)(C)
        \coil{$L$}      
        \capacitor{$C$}.
\end{pspicture}

    \caption{Filtre LC simple en configuration étoile}
    \label{filtre_lc_etoile_simple}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping there was something which could be done automatically by latex, however your solution is not complicated either. Thanks again.